# ImportError: cannot import name <module> only when running file from atom

Tags: python, import, atom-editor, importerror

Given two files on the directory */khwarizmi* such as */khwarizmi/linear.py* and */khwarizmi/exceptions.py*, importing functions and classes from one another works without problem when running the scripts through the OS command line (Ubuntu 18.04). Yet, when I run the scripts from Atom (whether it is from the `Hydrogen`, the `python-run` or the `script` packages, I get

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/santiago/Documentos/ScriptLab/Repos/khwarizmi/khwarizmi/linear.py", line 1, in <module>
    from exceptions import (InvalidFormError, LinearSolutionError,
ImportError: cannot import name InvalidFormError
[Finished in 0.074s]
```

This is how the imports are written:

```
 from exceptions import (InvalidFormError, LinearSolutionError,
                        RedundantConversionError)

# The following are other imports that, provided
# they were executed, raise the same error.

import equations
from equations import operators
from lib.misc import cond_assign, num
```

I tried tweaking the packages settings that would seem relevant; for example, changing the **Default CWD** setting from *first project directory* to *project directory of the script* or *directory of the script*, but this didn't change anything.

My question is, why doesn't this work when running the scripts from Atom packages, but it does from the command line?

(If you want to see how the repository is structured, or the full code, see: https://github.com/lpereyrasantiago/khwarizmi )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

exceptions is a python standard module. If you use same name for your private module, this may mix-up.

Comment: You were right. I don't know why the command line understood it and not the atom interpreters, but it solved it anyway, so thank you.

Unfortunately, the interpreters still have problems. For example,

eval("(9-2*1)/5")

evaluates to 1.4 on the command line (which is right), but to 1 on the interpreters. So... I guess I'll stick to the command line. Thanks.